# After setting bookmark: `Wrong type argument: listp, "~/.spacemacs`

Tags: spacemacs, bookmarks, error-handling

So I did just `M-x bookmark-save` in my original `.spacemacs` file, which lead to the case that when I booted Spacemacs, I get the following error:

```
Upgrading bookmark format from 0 to 1...
mapcar: Wrong type argument: listp, "~/.spacemacs"PNG warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
```

So I had to reset (basically rename) my `.spacemacs` file, to be able to start Spacemacs again.

But this error comes again when I try to set a bookmark in my `.spacemacs` file again:

```
Upgrading bookmark format from 0 to 1...
condition-case: Wrong type argument: listp, "~/.spacemacs"
```

I am using  the most recent versions of ManjaroI3 and Spacemacs, btw.

Comment: I get such an error because I had diff markers in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Upgrading bookmark format from 0 to 1..."

This message comes from the function `bookmark-upgrade-file-format-from-0` which was added to Emacs 24 years ago.  I presume that you don't *actually* have such an old bookmark file format, but something in your file is causing a false-positive detection of that format, and consequently breaking when it tries to convert it.

The function `bookmark-grok-file-format-version` decides the version.  Specifically, it requires that the first line of the file begins with `;;;;` and then returns the first digit in that line as the version.  If it can't do that, it treats it as version 0.

Your bookmark file *ought* to start with:

```
;;;; Emacs Bookmark Format Version 1
```

If it doesn't, you *might* simply be able to edit that into the start of the file (if the file is otherwise valid).

n.b. <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `bookmark-default-file` defines your bookmark file name.

Comment: I unfortunately destroyed my filesystem and now I can't reproduce it anymore. But thanks for your detailed answer either way :)

Comment: ...and http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/etc/NEWS?id=e94d01f1aceba364f8b55978eed854127a08264b :)